# Changing BY in app store

Tags: iphone, ios

I'v just uploaded my application to app store. Searched for this for a while, but couldn't find an answer. 
In app store  it shows like "Application name" BY realname. Is there any way to change that? I know that changing seller name is not very easy, but i have seen individual developers without showing real name in after BY. So how can i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual developers can get a [DBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doing_business_as) to do business as something besides their real name. You'll need to get in contact with Apple by email and they'll request that you fax them copies of your DBA to verify that yo have the right to use it, and they'll switch the name at their discretion. They may have an issue with you switching from a personal-type account (your real name) to a business-type account (the DBA), so it might be worth emailing them ahead of time to see if they'll allow you to do it without creating a new developer account.

Answer (score 0):

You are an Individual Developer. Therefore your full name is shown. If you want to change it, join Apple Developer Program as Company Developer.